Recommended vite.config.js for compilation of individual Vue components
I am working on a project with a specific file structure in which I have compiled vue components imported in a html page. These compiled js files are a built using vite. The project will most likely end up in a scenario where we will have shared components and pages importing a plethora of components in which those components have nested components in them as well.
I'm still a bit green around vite as I have normally used webpack before. I would like to know the recommended build options for vite for a development/production build.
I have made a replica of my file structure and project here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8rzupw?file=vite.config.js
I have just been using the basic config for Vue:
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
})

I have also looked at Library Mode in Vite as it would currently fit my use case.
In summary, what Vite build options would suit a use case where individually compiled Vue components, employing progressive enhancement, are imported into HTML pages via script tags.

If you want to be able to put your project in development/production mode, you can modify it by adding the corresponding mode to your config.
export default defineConfig({
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    minify: false,
    target: 'modules',
    inlineConfig: true,
  },
});

With this you will deactivate optimization which will compile your builds faster.

Would you recommend other config options like build.rollupOptions to further optimize build speeds?
In summary, what more Vite build options would suit a use case where individually compiled Vue components, employing progressive enhancement, are imported into HTML pages via script tags?
